# Local Maven can't pull down meta-data.xml files from our repository - Connection Refused

Tags: maven, plugins, connection, repository

I am troubleshooting errors I get when my local maven isn't able to pull down certain plugins and I receive errors that could not find artifactID, or unable to resolve dependencies for a certain artifact. I believe this issue is because my local maven isn't pulling down the metadata.xml files from our repository. When building certain projects I get the following errors:

```
> [INFO] Downloading:
> http://buildserver.companyA.com/pub/mvn/com/evincible/EvncPluginIfc/4.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/EvncPluginIfc-4.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
> [INFO] Downloading:
> http://buildserver.companyA.com/pub/mvn/com/evincible/EvncAcFilter/4.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
> [WARNING] Could not transfer metadata
> com.evincible:EvncAcFilter:4.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to
> buildserver.companyA.com (http://buildserver.companyA.com/pub/mvn/):
> Connect to buildserver.companyA.com:80
> [buildserver.companyA.com/000.50.40.9] failed: Connection refused:
> connect [WARNING] Failure to transfer
> com.evincible:EvncAcFilter:4.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from
> http://buildserver.companyA.com/pub/mvn/ was cached in the local
> repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
> interval of buildserver.companyA.com has elapsed or updates are
> forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata
> com.evincible:EvncAcFilter:4.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to
> buildserver.companyA.com (http://buildserver.companyA.com/pub/mvn/):
> Connect to buildserver.companyA.com:80
> [buildserver.companyA.com/000.50.40.9] failed: Connection refused:
> connect
> 
> 
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project XcertDA: Could not resolve
> dependencies for project
> com.companyA.xcert:XcertDA:jar:4.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect
> dependencies at com.companyA.xcert:XoShared:jar:4.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT:
> Failed to read artifact descriptor for
> com.companyA.xcert:XoShared:jar:4.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer
> artifact  com.companyA.xcert:XoShared:pom:4.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT from/to
> buildserver.companyA.com (http://buildserver.companyA.com/pub/mvn/):
> Connect to buildserver.companyA.com:80
> [buildserver.companyA.com/000.50.40.9] failed: Connection refused:
> connect -> [Help]
```

Comment: "Connection refused" seems quite clear? do you need to configure a proxy for maven? can you open that repository in a browser on that developer machine?

Comment: I have my proxy configured correctly as it's been the same for years now. I am able to open the repository in a browser and few the contents. The issue seems to be that our repository manager is "refusing connections" when it comes to pulling down meta-data files. So I'm not sure if it's a local maven that needs to be reconfigured, or if something has changed on our repository manager.